# Migrating Full Trust solutions to App Model

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-addin, migration, farm-solution

IS there a way/tool to convert existing Full trust Farm solutions to App Model or we will have to rewrite and re-architect all solutions?

Answer (score 3):

Since you need to use the Client Object Model for apps, you will have to rewrite large parts (if not all) of your back-end code.